# UI is frozen while running Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

May be I am wrong but my assuption is that any background thread can read and write into List or ObservableCollection if I don't care about any particular order. If I need a surtain order I will use BlockingCollection.

```
    private void buttonTesting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrepareDataForTesting();                
        Stopwatch timer1 = new Stopwatch();
        timer1.Start();           

        //some code preparing data

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            //Testing for each pair 
        foreach (InterfaceWithClassName aCompound in Group1) 
        { 
            foreach (InterfaceWithClassName bCompound in Group2) 
            { 
                InstancePair pair = new InstancePair(); 
                //some code 

                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestPairSerial(pair));
                 tasks.Add(task);
             }
          }                

            var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(),
                antecedents =>
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    TimeSpan ts1 = timer1.Elapsed;
                    string elapsedTime1 = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts1.Hours, ts1.Minutes, ts1.Seconds, ts1.Milliseconds / 10);
                    statusLabel_1.Content = "Elapsed time to run the test" + elapsedTime1;
                    statusLabel_0.Content = "Testing made " + passes + " passes";
                    pairsResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = pairsResultsTable.DefaultView;
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();

                }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, ui);            

                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();               
            }
```

(Note: I am not sure if it matters - "pair" is found through Reflection)
 When I click the button I can hear the last line - System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); meaning we out of the event handler and all the threads are launched. But then my application is still frozen untill ContinueWhenAll is done. 
TestPairSerial(pair) method has the following structure:

```
private void TestPairSerial(object instances)
    {
      do 
      { 
          do 
           { 
             //here are two methods that read data from minData ObservableCollection
             //minData is a public static property of MainWindow
             //minData is bound to Chart control (in XAML)

            } while (isSetbCompoundParams); 

        } while (isSetaCompoundParams); 

              //filling up results into one table and two dictionaries (main window variables)
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of your method? Also you may try to pause execution when UI is frozen and see where mainthread is stopped.

Comment: I tried to pause and yes it is inside of the one of multiple methods (inside TestPairSerial). Sorry there are too many of them and too much code to show (I tried my best to show the essence).

Comment: I tried to ask the same question on MSDN forum. Looks like their answer makes sense. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/74b2c600-83ad-4890-b2b2-27d8f07f5a90

Comment: Main point from there answer is: "Anything bound to the View is going to require marshaling back to the UI thread.  You should consider reworking this so that the analytical portion happens on the background thread, and then you can update your collections at the end on the UI thread."

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the tasks in the main thread. You can execute the whole code asynchronously with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    // your code here
}), null);
```

Comment: By default as soon as Task starts it is running asyncroniously. I used the following blog as an example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx

Comment: That's true, but the rest of your code doesn't. It doesn't hurt to wrap your whole code in the above block I suggested. You may find it useful.

Comment: Sorry. I just tried it didn't work. The same result. My guess is - the reason is someware in constant communication between mainWindow variables and an async thread.